# Hosting JavaFX project on docker container

Tags: java, docker, javafx, dockerfile, glx

I am having trouble hosting my JavaFX GUI application on a docker container. My JavaFX GUI application is in a single executable jar file: `start.jar`
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

RUN mkdir logs

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libglu1-mesa xvfb -y && apt-get update

RUN apt-get install xvfb

COPY library/javafx-sdk-11.0.2 javafx-sdk-11.0.2 

COPY start.jar start.jar

ENV DISPLAY=:99

COPY run.sh /run.sh

RUN chmod a+x /run.sh

CMD /run.sh
```

And `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/.X99-lock #needed when docker container is restarted
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp &
java --module-path javafx-sdk-11.0.2 -jar start.jar
```

When I run my `start.jar` application, I get this error:

```
ES2 Prism: Error - GLX extension is not supported
    GLX version 1.3 or higher is required
```

How can I update to the correct GLX version so I can successfully run my JavaFX GUI application on docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try **disabling the hardware graphics acceleration** dependency, by setting a software pipeline for `Prism`. This can be done by setting the *param* **`-Dprism.order=sw`**.

So the java command inside **`run.sh`** should change to:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/.X99-lock #needed when docker container is restarted
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp &
java -Dprism.order=sw --module-path javafx-sdk-11.0.2-jar start.jar
```

Comment: That fixed the issue. I don't get any errors when I run the ```java``` command to execute my jar file but my GUI does not show up. Is it even possible to run a JavaFX GUI application inside a docker container?